# Python left() equivalent?

Tags: python, django

I'm just learning Python and Django.

I want to get only the end value of the following string 'col' the end value is always a number i.e. col1, col2 etc

In other languages I could do this many ways...

```
left(value,3) - only leave the value after 3.
findreplace(value, 'col', '') - fine the string col replace with blank leaving nothing but the number I need.
```

So my question is,  **within Django (Python) how can I do these things?**  *(in a view not a template)*

Also is Django strict? will I need to int the value to make it a number after?

Comment: It's called "slicing" and is in the Python tutorial: eg: value[3:] - will take the 3 character onwards... (0 based indexed)

Comment: @Jon Clements 'slicing' easy when you know what its called! So can you do from the left to the right position?

Comment: @User7 Yep! And right to left with the use of negative integers :).

Comment: Note: the text and title is wrong. The OP is looking for x=Right(value,Len(value)-3).  The "Left" keyword characteristicaly returns the LEFT part of a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html):

```
>>> s = "Hello World!"
>>> print s[2:] # From the second (third) letter, print the whole string
llo World!
>>> print s[2:5] # Print from the second (third) letter to the fifth string
llo
>>> print s[-2:] # Print from right to left
d!
>>> print s[::2] # Print every second letter
HloWrd
```

So for your example:

```
>>> s = 'col555'
>>> print s[3:]
555
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know it will always be `col` followed by some numbers:

```
>>> int('col1234'[3:])
1234
```